# Real Safari Emulator on Windows or Linux for Web Designers

Tags: safari, emulation

Is possible to check my websites, when I develop them, in Safari?
I don't have any Apple product so I want to see my websites in an emulator of Safari on Linux or Windows.

But I want a real emulator to see exactly how my websites looks on a safari, because I find some online emulators of Safari which is fake and dont compile the real view of site such as in real apple devices

Answer (score 0):

"Is possible to check my websites, when I develop them, in Safari? I don't have any Apple product so I want to see my websites in an emulator of Safari on Linux or Windows.

But I want a real emulator to see exactly how my websites looks on a safari, because I find some online emulators of Safari which is fake and dont compile the real view of site such as in real apple devices"
Any answer 3 years later?